# How autoconf generate the "make install" action

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I m trying to change the `make install` action of the open source `json-c`.

I tried to check the `configure.ac` and the `makefile.am`. But it's not clear for me how these files build the make install action.

Here after the `configuer.ac` and `makefile.am`

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ(2.52)

# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
AC_INIT([json-c], 0.12.99, [json-c@googlegroups.com])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_PROG_MAKE_SET

AC_ARG_ENABLE(rdrand,
 AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-rdrand],
   [Enable RDRAND Hardware RNG Hash Seed generation on supported x86/x64 platforms.]),
[if test x$enableval = xyes; then
  enable_rdrand=yes
  AC_DEFINE(ENABLE_RDRAND, 1, [Enable RDRANR Hardware RNG Hash Seed])
fi])

if test "x$enable_rdrand" = "xyes"; then
  AC_MSG_RESULT([RDRAND Hardware RNG Hash Seed enabled on supported x86/x64 platforms])
else
  AC_MSG_RESULT([RDRAND Hardware RNG Hash Seed disabled. Use --enable-rdrand to enable])
fi

# enable silent build by default
m4_ifdef([AM_SILENT_RULES], [AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])])

# Checks for programs.

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
AC_CONFIG_HEADER(config.h)
AC_CONFIG_HEADER(json_config.h)
AC_HEADER_STDC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(fcntl.h limits.h strings.h syslog.h unistd.h [sys/cdefs.h] [sys/param.h] stdarg.h locale.h endian.h)
AC_CHECK_HEADER(inttypes.h,[AC_DEFINE([JSON_C_HAVE_INTTYPES_H],[1],[Public define for json_inttypes.h])])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_C_CONST
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_VPRINTF
AC_FUNC_MEMCMP
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
AC_CHECK_FUNCS(strcasecmp strdup strerror snprintf vsnprintf vasprintf open vsyslog strncasecmp setlocale)
AC_CHECK_DECLS([INFINITY], [], [], [[#include <math.h>]])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([nan], [], [], [[#include <math.h>]])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([isnan], [], [], [[#include <math.h>]])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([isinf], [], [], [[#include <math.h>]])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([_isnan], [], [], [[#include <float.h>]])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([_finite], [], [], [[#include <float.h>]])

if test "$ac_cv_have_decl_isnan" = "yes" ; then
   AC_TRY_LINK([#include <math.h>], [float f = 0.0; return isnan(f)], [], [LIBS="$LIBS -lm"])
fi

#check if .section.gnu.warning accepts long strings (for __warn_references)
AC_LANG_PUSH([C])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([if .gnu.warning accepts long strings])
AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
extern void json_object_get();
__asm__(".section .gnu.json_object_get,\n\t.ascii \"Please link against libjson-c instead of libjson\"\n\t.text");

int main(int c,char* v) {return 0;}
]])], [
    AC_DEFINE(HAS_GNU_WARNING_LONG, 1, [Define if .gnu.warning accepts long strings.])
    AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
], [
   AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
])

AC_LANG_POP([C])

AM_PROG_LIBTOOL

# Check for the -Bsymbolic-functions linker flag
AC_ARG_ENABLE([Bsymbolic],
              [AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-Bsymbolic], [Avoid linking with -Bsymbolic-function])],
              [],
              [enable_Bsymbolic=check])

AS_IF([test "x$enable_Bsymbolic" = "xcheck"],
      [
        saved_LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
        AC_MSG_CHECKING([for -Bsymbolic-functions linker flag])
        LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
        AC_TRY_LINK([], [int main (void) { return 0; }],
                    [
                      AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
                      enable_Bsymbolic=yes
                    ],
                    [
                      AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
                      enable_Bsymbolic=no
                    ])
        LDFLAGS="${saved_LDFLAGS}"
      ])

AS_IF([test "x$enable_Bsymbolic" = "xyes"], [JSON_BSYMBOLIC_LDFLAGS=-Wl[,]-Bsymbolic-functions])
AC_SUBST(JSON_BSYMBOLIC_LDFLAGS)

AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([-Wall -Werror -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations])
AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([-Wextra -Wwrite-string -Wno-unused-parameter])
AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([-std=gnu99])
AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([
Makefile
json-c.pc
tests/Makefile
json-c-uninstalled.pc
])

AC_OUTPUT
```

**makefile.am**

```
EXTRA_DIST = README.html README-WIN32.html config.h.win32 doc json-c.vcproj
SUBDIRS = . tests

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libjson-c.la 

pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = json-c.pc

libjson_cincludedir = $(includedir)/json-c
libjson_cinclude_HEADERS = \
    arraylist.h \
    bits.h \
    debug.h \
    json.h \
    json_config.h \
    json_c_version.h \
    json_inttypes.h \
    json_object.h \
    json_object_iterator.h \
    json_object_private.h \
    json_tokener.h \
    json_util.h \
    linkhash.h \
    printbuf.h \
    random_seed.h

#libjsonx_includedir = $(libdir)/json-c-@VERSION@
#
#libjsonx_include_HEADERS = \
#   json_config.h

libjson_c_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 3:0:0 -no-undefined @JSON_BSYMBOLIC_LDFLAGS@

libjson_c_la_SOURCES = \
    arraylist.c \
    debug.c \
    json_c_version.c \
    json_object.c \
    json_object_iterator.c \
    json_tokener.c \
    json_util.c \
    linkhash.c \
    printbuf.c \
    random_seed.c


distclean-local:
    -rm -rf $(testsubdir)
    -rm -rf config.h.in~ Makefile.in aclocal.m4 autom4te.cache/ config.guess config.sub depcomp install-sh ltmain.sh missing
    -rm -f INSTALL test-driver tests/Makefile.in compile

maintainer-clean-local:
    -rm -rf configure

uninstall-local:
    rm -rf "$(DESTDIR)@includedir@/json-c"
    rm -f "$(DESTDIR)@includedir@/json"

ANDROID_CFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) -DHAVE_CONFIG_H

Android.mk: Makefile.am
    androgenizer -:PROJECT json-c \
        -:SHARED libjson-c \
        -:TAGS eng debug \
        -:REL_TOP $(top_srcdir) -:ABS_TOP $(abs_top_srcdir) \
        -:SOURCES $(libjson_c_la_SOURCES) $(nodist_libjson_c_la_SOURCES) \
        -:CFLAGS $(DEFS) $(ANDROID_CFLAGS) $(libjson_c_la_CFLAGS) \
        -:LDFLAGS $(libjson_c_la_LDFLAGS) $(libjson_c_la_LIBADD) \
        -:HEADER_TARGET json-c \
        -:HEADERS $(libjson_cinclude_HEADERS) \
        -:PASSTHROUGH LOCAL_ARM_MODE:=arm \
    > $@
```

Coul you help me by indicating the parts that build the make install

Comment: There's nothing of interest in here for anyone following the c or json tags, so they shouldn't be here. autoconf is combined with automake, and that's actually what generates the Makefile. I strongly recommend reading its documentation and/or a basic tutorial.

Comment: In what way are you trying to modify the install command?  automake provides various hooks that allow you to customize how 'make install' works, and whatever you are trying to accomplish can probably be done within the standard framework.

Answer (score 2):

The main way that Automake decides how to install things is via the prefix of the "primaries".

In your example above, these are `lib_LTLIBRARIES`, which means "libraries installed in `libdir`"; and `pkgconfig_DATA`, which means "data files installed in `pkgconfigdir`" -- and `pkgconfigdir` itself is defined in `Makefile.am`.  (This second one shows how the list of such prefixes can be extended.)

You can also install things by writing explicit rules, though the above method is really the superior one -- install rules have some subtleties, like `DESTDIR` support, that hand-written rules often get wrong.

For what it's worth, there's an entire chapter on the `install` process in the Automake manual.  I recommend at least skimming the entire manual.